# xmlstarlet count with star

Tags: xmlstarlet

I have this line command with xmlstarlet to return how many name=$VALOR there is at the file client_state.xml. But I want to select a value with star, like $VALOR*

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(/client_state/workunit[name='$VALOR'])" client_state.xml
```

How do I do it?

Thanks

Felipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming by "with star" you mean to use the star as a wildcard. You can use the XPath function [starts-with()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) for this case:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(/client_state/workunit[starts-with(name, '$VALOR')])" client_state.xml
```